# Keeping type info between methods in Scala

Tags: scala, type-safety

Here is my problem: I have a large sequence of objects on which I want to apply procedures (which I call "compilers"), if some predicate apply. For clarity, I want to separate the predicate function from the procedure; however in many case the predicate may be quite complex, and builds information that I would like to reuse in my latter procedure function.

I define a compiler as follows:

```
trait Compiler[A] {
  def mtch(o: SourceObject): Option[A]
  def proceed(o: SourceObject, data: A): Unit
}
```

And how compilers are called:

```
val compilers: Seq[Compiler[_]]
val objects: Seq[SourceObject]

for (o <- objects; c <- compilers; data <- c.mtch(o)) {
  c.proceed(o, data)
}
```

That is, if the `mtch` function returns `Some(data)`, then the `proceed` method is called, with `data` attached. However, I cannot compile this, as I do not know the type of data when I manage my compilers.

Moreover, I have cases where I do not actually need any data. In my current state, I have the matcher return `Some(null)`, which stinks.

Comment: Well, it seems that replacing the placeholder `_` by `AnyRef` and add some covariance works here, but I still have my `null` issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with path-dependent types instead. Replace

```
trait Compiler[A] {
  def mtch(o: SourceObject): Option[A]
  def proceed(o: SourceObject, data: A): Unit
}
```

with

```
trait Compiler {
  type A
  def mtch(o: SourceObject): Option[A]
  def proceed(o: SourceObject, data: A): Unit
}
```

and everything will work.

The trick here is that the type of `data` in your for-comprehension becomes `c.A`, which is the type `c.proceed` expects as its second parameter.

As for `null`, make compiler which don't need to pass parameters `type A = Unit`, so you return `Some(())` if it should proceed.